# Angular 2 and backend api communication

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am doing ionic aws application and I've done front-end. Now I have :

**Front-end repo:**

1. Ionic front-end

**Backend repos :**

2. Example resources
3. Example get
4. Example post
5. Example auth

Front-end angular 2 ionic 4, backend aws. How to communicate between front and back-end right here ?

Answer (score -1):

You should use HTTP protocol. Angular official documentation is a good starting point if you don’t know how it works: [Angular - HTTP](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: I read all, but can't understand if I need url of a repo file, or to download repo and use it like import ?

Comment: Do AWS provides you endpoints (like https://mybaseurl.com/login) that you can call using Angular HTTP library? You should find them into AWS platform

Comment: Yes there are some endpoints in all repos ( : "endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000',"

Comment: So you should call that endpoints with HTTP Client to communicate with you backend

Comment: But it's localhost:8000, it should be normal url or... ?

Comment: “Localhost” as base url mean that you have to run your server locally, otherwise you should start your backend in AWS and use the AWS base path to communicate instead of “localhost”

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178797/discussion-between-angulandy2-and-samuel-roberto).

Answer (score -1):

Amazon AWS added support for Ionic using 'aws-amplify' npm package. You can install using

```
npm install --save aws-amplify # or yarn add aws-amplify
npm install --save aws-amplify-angular # or yarn add aws-amplify-angular
npm install --save ionic-angular
```

It also supports AWS-Amplify CLI which will ease the integration with AWS Backend server. For more onformation. please refer the below Link.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/ionic_guide